# Multiple Alerts with Audio

Tags: javascript, html, css, audio, alert

Hey everyone so what I am trying to accomplish is producing this fake A.I.. I was playing around with my code and I changed something over the past while and now it's not working.

What I am trying to do is to have multiple alerts,
the first alert being- 'hello'
the second alert 'is something there'
and so on and so on.

I'm trying to attach these alerts using a particular voice in an mp3. file.

So an alert pops-up and the audio goes off.
How can I connect them?

I'm just learning code, so please forgive my lack of knowledge.

```
<body onload="delayedAlert();">

<script>

var timeoutID;

function delayedAlert() {
  timeoutID = window.setTimeout(slowAlert, 50);
}

function slowAlert() {
 var audio= document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
 const audio2 = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[1];
 var audio3 = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[2];
  var audio4 = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[3];

audio.play(); 
var myvar1;alert('Hello?');

audio2.play(); 
var myvar1;alert('Is something here?');

audio3.play();
var myvar2;alert('Something is here.');

audio4.play();

const name = prompt('What is your name?')

const sentence = 'Hello,' + name +'I am Eve'+name+name+name+name+'What does a' +name +' look like?';
responsiveVoice.speak(sentence, "US English Female", {
    rate: 0.4,
  onend: function() {
    // Redirect after sentence has been spoke
    location.replace('https://www.eves.website/eve_2.html');
  }
});
};


</script>

 <audio>
  <source src="audio/hello.wav" type="audio/wav" preload=true>
 </audio>

 <audio>
  <source src="audio/is_something_here.wav" type="audio/wav" preload=true>
 </audio>

  <audio>
  <source src="audio/oh_something_is_here.wav" type="audio/wav" preload=true>
 </audio>


 <audio>
 <source src="audio/what_is_your_name.wav" type="audio/wav" preload=true>
 </audio>



        <video autoplay="autoplay" preload="auto" id="video" src="images/evetwo.mp4" width="1300px" height="auto" style="position:absolute; z-index:-1;" >
        Video not supported.
         </video>






</body>
</html>
```